# Input a filename as a string and return a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, filenames

I have the function:

```
def make_happiness_table("word-happiness.csv"):
   ''' make_happiness_table: string -> dict
      creates a dictionary of happiness scores from the given file '''

   return {}
```

But I keep getting a syntax error when trying to run the program.

```
File "happiness.py", line 13
def make_happiness_table("word-happiness.csv"):
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I suppose the natural question for you is what do you expect `"word-happiness.csv"` to do in this context?  Are you expecting it to be associated with the returned dictionary?  Is it supposed to be a parameter to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```py
def make_happiness_table(filename="word-happiness.csv"):
   ''' make_happiness_table: string -> dict
      creates a dictionary of happiness scores from the given file '''

   return {}
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't give an actual filename in your function definition, give a variable that is filled in when the function is called, like so:

```
def make_happiness_table(filename):
   ''' make_happiness_table: string -> dict
      creates a dictionary of happiness scores from the given file '''

   return {}

make_happiness_table("word-happiness.csv")
```

Comment: I think this is the better answer. The OP seems to be confusing the function definition with calling the function. Making it a default value seems a strange way to "fix" the error.